# What is new in The Witcher 2 version 2.0 (Enhanced Edition)?

Tags: the-witcher-2

As this game is on sale today [on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/20920/), I checked it out and I saw the following message:

> The Witcher 2 new & improved version 2.0 coming on September 29th!

What is new on this new & improved 2.0 version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Eurogamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2011-09-22-witcher-2-2-0-dated-and-detailed):

- It includes **40 new technological and gameplay enhancements**, all nine DLC packs released for the game so far and three big new features.
- A new **tutorial** section has been bolted on in reaction to complaints that the game's opening section is too difficult. It takes the form of a short quest set in a small village in a forest.
- A new **Arena Mode**. Located in a forgotten stronghold in the kingdom of Kaedwan, you'll be able to scrap it out against various foes from the main game, and one new beast - the werewolf.

**A more detailed list of new feature/improvements** is available [here on PC Gamer](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/09/28/witcher-2-version-2-0-overhauls-combat-adds-dark-mode-and-battle-arena-out-tomorrow/).

This content is available for free to all PC customers and it will be the base for the XBox 360 adaptation, in development.

Comment: So it will be a PC game first, then ported to a console?  I thought I'd never see the day.  :]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/search?q=witcher+2+2.0

http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2011-08-17-witcher-2-2-0-update-adds-dark-mode

http://www.videogamer.com/pc/the_witcher_2/news/cd_projekt_details_witcher_2_2_0_update.html

"the free update brings with it technical enhancements, gameplay tweaks and major new features."

"The biggest new features are Dark Mode and Arena. Dark Mode is a new difficulty setting that ups the challenge and adds a number of powerful 'Dark' items. Arena mode is just what you think it is, pitting you against endless waves of enemies while you pick up vital XP."

"A new tutorial has also been added in order to help beginners through the early stages of the game."